# TripleDES algorithm in C#

Tags: c#, encryption, cryptography, tripledes

I'm currently working on TripleDES encryption in C# for which I've received the code sample from JAVA.

I have created an encryption function in C# with below code sample :

Inputs : 
key/ekay = "15ce89cd1a2a838f4f6d49d60438251915ce89cd1a2a838f"

text/data = "0000000000000000"

```
public static string encryptionMethod(string Text, string key)
{
          string encryptedText = string.Empty;
          try
            {                
                MD5CryptoServiceProvider md5Hash = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();                          
                byte[] md5Bytes = md5Hash.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key));
                md5Hash.Clear();
                byte[] clearBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Text);  
                TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider des = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();  
                des.KeySize = 128;                          
                des.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;    
                des.Padding = PaddingMode.None;  
                des.Key = md5Bytes;   //Passing key in byte array
                //des.BlockSize = 64;
                byte[] ivBytes = new byte[8] {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
                des.IV = ivBytes;                      
                ICryptoTransform ct = des.CreateEncryptor();   //Interface with some result
                byte[] resultArray = ct.TransformFinalBlock(clearBytes, 0, clearBytes.Length);               
                encryptedText = ByteArrayToHexString(resultArray);                               
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                return "";
            }
        return encryptedText;

}

public static string ByteArrayToHexString(byte[] ba)
        {
            StringBuilder hex = new StringBuilder(ba.Length * 2);
            foreach (byte b in ba)
                hex.AppendFormat("{0:x2}", b);
            return hex.ToString();
        }
```

but after comparing the C# output with JAVA output, I got the different results.

JAVA code

```
public  static String encrypt(String data, String ekey) {
        String encrypteddata = null;
   try{            
        String key = ekey;
        byte[] encryptKey = ISOUtil.hex2byte(key);        
        DESedeKeySpec spec = new DESedeKeySpec(encryptKey);
        SecretKeyFactory keyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DESede");
        SecretKey theKey = keyFactory.generateSecret(spec);        
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DESede/CBC/NoPadding");       
        IvParameterSpec IvParameters = new IvParameterSpec( new byte[] { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 });        
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, theKey, IvParameters);  
        String plain = data;       
        byte[] plaintext = ISOUtil.hex2byte(plain);
        byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(plaintext);        
         encrypteddata= ISOUtil.byte2hex(encrypted);             
    }
    catch(Exception e){        
    }
        return encrypteddata;      
    }
```

output :

C# : eca27a1e639900f3298a5090cc34dd29

JAVA : c0a946402dd20f5e

---

Any help would be appreciated?

Thanks.

Comment: Key generations are different. Note: c# prepends the IV.

Comment: Is DESede == TripleDES?

Comment: @bradbury9 Yes, DES EDE means DES encrypt-decrypt-encrypt, describing the encrypt operation of triple DES (officially 3-DEA I think, but triple DES is an alias recognized in the standard, and everybody uses that).

Comment: Um, one has MD5 the other one hasn't. One has hex, the other one hasn't. You're not even *trying*. Just copying code that uses triple DES doesn't mean that we're going to write the code for you.

Comment: Got it, Thanks !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the modified code, that has solved my issue.

```
 public static string encryptionMethod(string Text, string key)
        {
            string encryptedText = string.Empty;
            try
            {
                byte[] clearBytes = StringToByteArray(Text); ;//Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Text);
                TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider des = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
                des.KeySize = 128;
                des.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
                des.Padding = PaddingMode.None;
                des.Key = StringToByteArray(key);   //Passing key in byte array
                //des.BlockSize = 64;
                byte[] ivBytes = new byte[8] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
                des.IV = ivBytes;
                ICryptoTransform ct = des.CreateEncryptor();   //Interface with some result
                byte[] resultArray = ct.TransformFinalBlock(clearBytes, 0, clearBytes.Length);
                encryptedText = ByteArrayToHexString(resultArray);
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                return "";
            }
            return encryptedText;

        }


  public static byte[] StringToByteArray(string hex)
        {
            return Enumerable.Range(0, hex.Length)
                             .Where(x => x % 2 == 0)
                             .Select(x => Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(x, 2), 16))
                             .ToArray();
        }
```